# How to change the time of CSS transform

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a button that displays an arrow on hover and has a press down animation using

```
transform: translateY(3px);
```

It's working, but the button needs to be held to complete the animation.  Is there a way to set the speed of the animation so it doesn't have to be held?  I have a version of the button that just uses press that works in this way, but I'm guessing the translation time set for the arrow code is interfering.

Arrow and Press HTML:

```
    <button class="button-press-arrow"><span>Press Arrow</span></button>
```

Arrow and Press CSS:

```
button {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
}
.button-press-arrow {
  background-color: #f4511e;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #e09a84;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button-press-arrow span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button-press-arrow span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button-press-arrow:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button-press-arrow:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.button-press-arrow:active{
    box-shadow: 0 2px #e09a84;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

Comment: can you provide a working snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to do this with javascript.
Create a class `.button-active`

```
.button-active {
    box-shadow: 0 2px #e09a84;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

and with javascript add the class when the button is clicked

```
<script>
$(".button-press-arrow").click(function() {
    $(".button-press-arrow").addClass("button-active");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that I understand the question. If you want the animation to continue after the user lets go of the button, then you have to use javascript to accomplish this.

Without a dependency on Jquery, something like

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassname('button-press-arrow')[0]
element.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  element.className += 'animation-class-name'
  setTimeout(timeInMilliseconds, function () {
    element.className = 'button-press-arrow'
  }
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with just CSS, but you can add a class on `mousedown` via JS, then setup an event listener for the `transitionend` event and remove that class once the transition finishes.

Slowed the transition down for the example.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('transitionend',function() {
  this.classList.remove('press');
})

button.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) {
  this.classList.add('press');
})
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
}

.button-press-arrow {
  background-color: #f4511e;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #e09a84;
  transition: transform 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button-press-arrow span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button-press-arrow span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button-press-arrow:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button-press-arrow:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

.button-press-arrow:active {
  box-shadow: 0 2px #e09a84;
}

.press {
  transform: translateY(8px);
}
```

```html
<button id="button" class="button-press-arrow"><span>Press Arrow</span></button>
```